# Can I iterate over columns of a composite type?

Tags: oracle, plsql

Let's say I have the following table named `bar`:

```
key    | columnA   | columnB   | columnC
A      | B         | C         | D
E      | F         | G         | H
```

I want to write a function taking a key and a string and doing the following (best described by examples):

- Input: (`'A'`, `'${columnB} - ${columnA}'`) / Output : `'C - B'`
- Input: (`'B'`, `'Hello ${columnC}'`) / Output: `'Hello H'`

For the moment, I have this implementation:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo
( param_key IN VARCHAR2
, format_string IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    my_row bar%ROWTYPE;
    retval VARCHAR2(4000);
BEGIN
    BEGIN SELECT * INTO my_row FROM bar WHERE "key" = param_key;
    EXCEPTION WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN RETURN NULL;
    END;

    retval := format_string;
    retval := REPLACE(retval, '${columnA}', my_row.columnA);
    retval := REPLACE(retval, '${columnB}', my_row.columnB);
    retval := REPLACE(retval, '${columnC}', my_row.columnC);

    RETURN retval;
END;
/
```

I would like to avoid enumerating all columns one by one in the last part, because the structure of my table can change (new columns for instance). Is there a way to iterate on all columns of `my_row`, and to replace `${the column name}` with the value stored in that column, in a generic way?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more efficient solution is this one. For sure you have to write more code and it uses the full scope of dynamic SQL.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo (param_key IN VARCHAR2, format_string IN VARCHAR2) 
RETURN VARCHAR2 IS

    retval VARCHAR2(4000) := format_string;

    cur SYS_REFCURSOR;
    curId  INTEGER;

    descTab DBMS_SQL.DESC_TAB;
    colCnt NUMBER;

    numvar NUMBER;
    datevar DATE;
    namevar VARCHAR2(4000);
    tsvar TIMESTAMP;

BEGIN

    OPEN cur FOR SELECT * FROM bar WHERE "key" = param_key;
    curId := DBMS_SQL.TO_CURSOR_NUMBER(cur);

    DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS(curId, colCnt, descTab);
    -- Define columns
    FOR i IN 1..colcnt LOOP
        IF desctab(i).col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_NUMBER THEN
            DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(curid, i, numvar);
        ELSIF desctab(i).col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_DATE THEN
            DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(curid, i, datevar);
        ELSIF desctab(i).col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP THEN
            DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(curid, i, tsvar);
        ELSIF desctab(i).col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 THEN
            DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(curid, i, namevar, 4000);
        --ELSIF desctab(i).col_type = ... THEN
            --DBMS_SQL.DEFINE_COLUMN(curid, i, ...);    
        END IF;
    END LOOP;

    -- Fetch Rows
    IF DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(curid) > 0 THEN
        -- Fetch only the first row and do not consider if further rows exist, 
        -- otherwise use WHILE DBMS_SQL.FETCH_ROWS(curid) > 0 LOOP
        FOR i IN 1..colcnt LOOP
            IF desctab(i).col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_VARCHAR2 THEN
                DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, i, namevar);
                retval := REPLACE(retval, '${'||desctab(i).col_name||'}', namevar);
            ELSIF desctab(i).col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_NUMBER THEN
                DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, i, numvar);
                retval := REPLACE(retval, '${'||desctab(i).col_name||'}', numvar);
            ELSIF desctab(i).col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_DATE THEN
                DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, i, datevar);
                retval := REPLACE(retval, '${'||desctab(i).col_name||'}', datevar);
            ELSIF desctab(i).col_type = DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_TIMESTAMP THEN
                DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, i, tsvar);
                retval := REPLACE(retval, '${'||desctab(i).col_name||'}', tsvar);
            --ELSIF desctab(i).col_type = ... THEN
                --DBMS_SQL.COLUMN_VALUE(curid, i, ...);
                --retval := REPLACE(retval, '${'||desctab(i).col_name||'}', ...);           
            END IF;
        END LOOP;
    ELSE
        retval := NULL;
    END IF;
    DBMS_SQL.CLOSE_CURSOR(curId);

    RETURN retval;  

END;
```

Comment: Thank you. I did something close to that.

Answer (score 3):

Another way to achieve this.
Create xmltype from table row. 
Create xsl-transform from format_string.
Transform xml using xsl

```
declare 
v_string_format varchar2(200) := '{columnA} + {columnB} + {columnA}{columnB}';
v_key varchar2(10) := 'A';
v_cursor sys_refcursor; 
l_xml xmltype;
v_xslt VARCHAR2(500):='<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"><xsl:template match="/ROWSET/ROW">{patern}</xsl:template></xsl:stylesheet>';
begin 
-- create xsl transform
v_string_format :=  upper(v_string_format);
v_string_format := REPLACE(v_string_format,'{','<xsl:value-of select="');
v_string_format := REPLACE(v_string_format,'}','"/>');
v_xslt := replace(v_xslt,'{patern}',v_string_format);
dbms_output.put_line(v_string_format);
-- open cursor for table
 open v_cursor for select * from bar where key = v_key;
-- get v_cursor as xmltype. 
 l_xml := xmltype(v_cursor);
 -- print xml
 dbms_output.put_line(l_xml.getClobVal());
 -- tranform xml and print result 
 dbms_output.put_line(l_xml.transform(xmltype(v_xslt)).getClobVal());
 close v_cursor;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for this answer. I am not really comfortable with using an XML-based solution because I have the feeling that bad things can happen with undesirable characters like `<>&` in my format string. I still appreciate the solution you propose.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the result you are after using dynamic queries...

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo
( param_key IN VARCHAR2
, format_string IN VARCHAR2
)
RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
    retval VARCHAR2(4000) := format_string;
    cols SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST;
BEGIN
    SELECT  COLUMN_NAME
    BULK COLLECT INTO cols
    FROM    USER_TAB_COLUMNS
    WHERE   TABLE_NAME = 'bar'
    ORDER BY COLUMN_ID;

    FOR i IN 1 .. cols.COUNT LOOP
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT REPLACE( :1, ''${' || cols(i) || '}'', ' || cols(i) || ' ) FROM bar WHERE key = :2'
      INTO retval
      USING retval, param_key;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN retval;
EXCEPTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    RETURN NULL;
END;
/
```

... but:

- This uses dynamic SQL to query the table directly and does not use a `%ROWTYPE` record.
- You may not have access to `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` (or may need `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`) and the DBA might not want you to have access to the data dictionary tables.
- It is probably (almost certainly) very inefficient.
- I've seen this done before and never let it pass a code review (writing out the explicit column names has always seemed preferable).

So, while it is possible, I would say don't do this.

Comment: You have always access to `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` and `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS`. `USER_TAB_COLUMNS` contains your own table. `ALL_TAB_COLUMNS` contains all tables where you have access (but not necessarily `SELECT` privilege). You only may have a problem to select `DBA_TAB_COLUMNS`.

Comment: Thank you. I did not use this, because I tend to avoid using `execute immediate`, which is a bit like `eval` in other imperative languages. Moreover, as you say this would be inefficient as what I really do is working on a huge view with many joins, and `SELECT`ing many times would be slow.